# Why do my log messages appear in root logging file twice?

Tags: python, logging

I have script.py file in which I import requests module. I have noticed that by using root logger at the level DEBUG, I can log all GET requests which is nice.

But I would like to have another log file to log other messages at INFO level. So I did this:

```
# root logger to log all GET requests
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename= "allrequests.log", level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

# second logger to log only INFO
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
handler = logging.FileHandler('onlyinfo.log')
info_logger = logging.getLogger('second_logger')
info_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
info_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

the problem is now, whenever I use:

```
info_logger.info('my message')
```

it will log it twice in the first log file and once in the second file.

It would be fine, if it only logs info messages once in each file.

In other words I would like to log all messages (DEBUG and INFO level messages) in one log file and only INFO messages in another log file. How can I do this?

Comment: `basicConfig` is adding a handler to the root logger and you are attaching one to a sub-logger. Both will be called when the sub-logger has `propagate` set.

Comment: Is this is a good practice? How else can I inherit some of the messages from root logger? @KlausD.